# I have already install PyAudio lib from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ then this error is occured

Tags: pyaudio

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Chaman\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\VoiceAssistant.py", line 24, in <module>
sptext()
File "C:\Users\Chaman\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\VoiceAssistant.py", line 13, in sptext
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "C:\Users\Chaman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 138, in **enter**
self.audio.open(
File "C:\Users\Chaman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chaman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in **init**
self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error

please tell me the solution of this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Now error is resolved...